# Quadratic residue mod p

Tags: number-theory

For which primes p is 3 a quadratic residue modulo p?

From Quadratic Reciprocity -1/p = 1 if p = 1 mod 4 means that -1 is a quadratic residue mod p iff p = 1 mod 4. Similarly I know that I'm supposed to use 3/p = (p/3)(-1)^((p-1)/2) but how do I convert this to a similar form that gives the desired value of p?

Answer (score 0):

Recall what $(p/3)$ actually means. It depends on if the equation $x^2 \equiv p$ has (or has not) a solution modulo $3$. So you can (of course) reduce $p$ modulo $3$. So $(p/3)=1$ for $p$ equal $1$ mod $p$ and $-1$ for $2$ mod $3$.

Answer (score 0):

The prime $2$ is special. Certainly $3$ is a quadratic residue of $2$. Now look for primes $p\ge 5$ that have $3$ as a quadratic residue.

If $p$ has the form $4k+1$, then by Reciprocity we have $(3/p)=(p/3)$. This is $1$ precisely if $p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$. That gives us $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, $p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$. That system of congruences has the solution $p\equiv 1\pmod{12}$.

If $p$ has the form $4k+3$, then by Reciprocity we have $(3/p)=-(p/3)$. This is $1$ precisely if $p\equiv 2\pmod{3}$. That gives us $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$, $p\equiv 2\pmod{3}$. That is more pleasantly rewritten as $p\equiv -1\pmod{4}$, $p\equiv -1\pmod{3}$, which  has the solution $p\equiv -1\pmod{12}$.

Thus the odd primes that qualify are the primes $\equiv \pm 1\pmod{12}$.